# How to save an MMC console with remote computer snap in's

Tags: windows, mmc

I made an MMC console and added several snap ins to manage computers on my network. I saved it to my desktop and when I open it again every snap in is giving me information about the local computer instead of the remote computer I set up earlier. Is there any way to save the reference to the remote computer or do I have to re-connect manually every time ?

EDIT : I checked and this seems to only do this when I'm using the Performance Monitor snap in. The firewall/services/task scheduler/etc seems to retain their referenced computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With trial and error I managed to find the solution, here are the steps if other people encounter the same problem :

1. Open all the ports necessary, in this case **Performance Logs and Alerts** and **Windows Management Instrumentation**.
2. Start the services **Remote Procedure Call**(alongside **RPC Endpoint Mapper**) and **Remote Registry**
3. When when connecting to a computer on the Performance Monitor snap in, open the Performance(local) and *then* right-click connect to another computer.

When adding performance counters, I have a problem when adding % Processor Time, it simply doesn't show up. A solution to that is to select all the fields in the Processor group and then remove them one by one until % Processor Time remains. There seems to be a problem when adding only % Processor Time.

Comment: Aren't MSC/MMC files just XMLs? Perhaps you can manually edit them and add whatever's missing.

Comment: I'm guessing it would be possible but I had a look at the XML result of my console and didn't quite get it entirely. There is a <BinaryStorage> in which I'm guessing is the data from my snap in's. When expanding the <ScopeTree> attribute we can see references to indexes in the binary storage area. It just seemed easier to do it with the GUI.

Comment: Well, just thought it might turn out to be something easy to add. :) All I can suggest is looking up MSDN/TechNet articles for the format's specs, unless someone comes up with an easy GUI-based solution.

Answer (score -1):

You must run the MMC snapin in author mode and save it. Now copy the saved file to the system32 folder and override the old one. But when you do this, sfc will always tell you that files are damaged.